# How to grab the running total of the first day of the month?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write an Excel function to grab the value of the `Running Total` in rows that are on the first of the month in the `Date` column. Where there are more rows with the same date, I want to grab the last value. (The dates are in ascending order.)
This is an example of the kind of table I'm using:

| Income | Running Total | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $1,000.00 | $1,000.00 | Jun 30, 22 |
| -$60.00 | $940.00 | Jul 01, 22 |
| -$42.00 | $898.00 | Jul 20, 22 |
| -$55.00 | $843.00 | Aug 01, 22 |
| -$200.00 | $643.00 | Aug 01, 22 |
| -$60.00 | $583.00 | Aug 19, 22 |
| -$20.00 | $563.00 | Sep 01, 22 |
| $334.00 | $897.00 | Sep 10, 22 |
| -$610.00 | $287.00 | Oct 01, 22 |
| -$50.00 | $237.00 | Oct 02, 22 |

I have a formula for calculating the running total and the date is created with the `DATE()` function.

I'm planing to use the function in a new table on the same sheet. In each row is the running total of the first of that month.

| Month | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Jul |  |
| Aug |  |
| Sep |  |
| Oct |  |

The problem is that I'm expecting this table to grow and I don't want to manually search each row. I would like to have a function that goes through the `Date` column and identifies if it contains the date of the first day of the month, if it does, get the running total.

I have attempted something like this:

```
=CONCAT("$B",MATCH(”Jul 01, 22”,$C1:$C100,1))
```

But I don't know how to create the function or whether or not this works.
How can I write a function that grabs the Running Total on the first of the month?

Comment: Are these dates actual dates or text?

Comment: @P.b Actual dates

Comment: In that case Mayukh answered it very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` or `XLOOKUP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(DATE(2022,MONTH(E2&1),1),$C$2:$C$11,1))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=XLOOKUP(DATE(2022,MONTH(E2:E5&1),1),C2:C11,B2:B11,,1,-1)
```

---

or, can exclude the 5th parameter, of `XLOOKUP()` as well

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=XLOOKUP(DATE(2022,MONTH(E2:E5&1),1),C2:C11,B2:B11,,,-1)
```

---

Comment: @DušanStokić So glad to know it worked for you. Sounds Good 